# How to reference Angular2 component properties/methods without 'this' keyword?

Tags: angular, properties, closures, this

I am building an application on Angular2 and I have been constantly running into a problem with the 'this' keyword that keeps giving me trouble.  Since everything in my components (properties, methods) are just properties on a class, if I want to reference them within another method, I have to use the 'this' keyword, but sometimes I lose reference to it because I am nested so far into multiple functions.  I use closures a lot to fix this problem (shown below) but sometimes even closures don't work well because the closure function looses reference to a method that it uses inside of it (like a call to a service).  For example:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    private data;

    getInfoFromService() {
        this.data = this.myService.fetchAllInfo();
    }

    retrieveInformation() {
        var getInfo = this.getInfoFromService;
        setTimeout(function() {
            getInfo();
        }, 5000);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.retrieveInformation();
    }

}
```

Basically what I am getting at is, is there anyway to reference a method on a class without the 'this' keyword?  For example, could I write something like:

```
   retrieveInformation() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            MyComponent.getInfoFromService();  // instead of this.getInfoFromService()
        }, 5000);
    }
```

I know this syntax `MyComponent.getInfoFromService()` doesn't work, but is there anything like that that I could do?

Comment: You could use Dart ;-)

Comment: if you declare `getInfoFromService` as static you may use MyComponent.getInfoFromService().

Comment: you can assign `this` to a variable `let self = this`   in each function you need and then use it instead of `this` in nested functions